Filter strings with high proportion of lowercase letters
I have quite a large df (50+ million) with one of the columns containing DNA sequences (1 DNA sequence per row). Some of these sequences contain a mix of lowercase and uppercase letters. I would like to have my dataset only have sequences with 50% or more uppercase letters (take out the seqs with 50% or more lowercase).
I took a small subset of my DF and it took 2 minutes just to filter out the sequences. I was hoping that I could find a more efficient way so that I can scale up.
Example of my DF:
label    sequence
1        aaaggGtTt...
0        AAAggccCCC...

Here is the function I am using.
def remove_low_complexity_seqs(sequence, threshold=0.5):
    """
    Check if more than a given threshold proportion of the sequence is lowercase (low complexity).
    
    Args:
    - sequence (str): The nucleotide sequence.
    - threshold (float): The proportion threshold (default is 0.5 for 50%).
    
    Returns:
    - bool: True if more than threshold proportion is lowercase, otherwise False.
    """
    lowercase_count = sum(map(str.islower, sequence))
    proportion = lowercase_count / (10000) #10k is the length of all seqs

    return proportion > threshold

Code I ran:
# mask = control_seqs['sequence'].apply(lambda seq: not remove_low_complexity_seqs(seq, context)) # long runtime 115secs
# control_seqs = control_seqs[mask] # quick runtime


How long are the sequences?

10,000 letters long

10,000 each? 10,000 at the most? Even if we assume an average of 5,000, 50 million lines would require 250GB of memory, but do you have enough memory? Or are you running this in batches?

10K each. I have enough storage, but my RAM is limited to 80GB. I believe that is what is causing my code to crash. If you can add a solution with batching, that would be much appreciated.

The problem is that your data requires 500GB of memory just to load it. Therefore, we need to load only a small portion of the data piece by piece. To do this, please provide more details about how your data is stored in the storage. A small sample of the data would also be helpful.

I added in some notes to the original post.

I think you'd better remove the notes and instead post a new question. If I understand them correctly, most of your sequences are almost completely overlapping, so that it likely would be most efficient to not treat them individually but to use a proper sliding window calculation. Thus the added notes not just distract from your original question but also change it. And that after you got four answers which now all look inappropriate.

Assuming there are only the letters "acgtACGT", these seem 10-30 times faster (version 4 being the fastest):
Version 1:
lowercase_count = sum(map(sequence.count, 'acgt'))

Version 2:
lowercase_count = sum(map(sequence.encode().count, b'acgt'))

Version 3, with lower_to_a = bytes.maketrans(b'cgt', b'aaa') prepared once, before your function:
lowercase_count = sequence.encode().translate(lower_to_a).count(b'a')

Version 4, with del_upper = str.maketrans('', '', 'ACGT') prepared once, before your function:
lowercase_count = len(sequence.translate(del_upper))


A possible solution, based on numba. By using the same dataframe used by @ParmanM.Alizadeh, on my computer it took about 6 seconds to run:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit
def percentage(sequence, n = 100):
    count = 0
    
    for char in sequence:
        if char.isupper():
            count += 1
            
    return count / n

sequences = df['sequence'].values
m = np.array([percentage(seq) >= 0.5 for seq in sequences])

result = df[m]


By following the great advise, offered bellow in a comment by @JérômeRichard (to whom I very much thank), of previously converting the sequences to ascii, the execution time drops to less than 1 second!
EDIT: I have just tried with 1 million of random sequences of length 10000, which took 14 seconds on my computer.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit
def percentage(sequence, n=100):
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(n):
        if sequence[i] >= 65 and sequence[i] <= 90:  # ASCII range for uppercase letters
            count += 1
            
    return count / n

sequences = [seq.encode('ascii') for seq in df['sequence'].values]

m = np.array([percentage(seq) >= 0.5 for seq in sequences])

result = df[m]


Note Numba is generally very-slow for computing UTF-8 strings, but rather fast for ASCII ones. Here, df['sequence'].values is a Numpy array of CPython UTF-8 string objects. An ASCII conversion may significantly speed up this code.

Thanks a lot, @JérômeRichard: by following your great advice, the execution time drops to less than a second!

How about sequences of the correct length (the OP's code and comment says length 10000)? So let's say 10000 times the sequence 'acgtACGT' * 1250. (My final solution takes me about 0.15 seconds for that).

Thansk, @nocomment, for commenting my solution. I think 10000 is the length of each sequence and not the total number of sequences, which appear to be 50+ million (quoting from the original question: I have quite a large df (50+ million) )

Yes, exactly. 10000 is the length of each sequence. Not 100. And you used length 100, no?

Yes, @nocomment, I used 1 million of sequences of length 100.

@nocomment:  I have just tried with 1 million of random sequences of length 10000, which took 14 seconds on my computer.

Pandas often struggle with datasets containing millions of records due to its memory usage and single-threaded operations. NumPy can offer improvements through vectorized operations, but it still falls short for extremely large datasets like yours. I would recommend using Polars to handle this issue. It's designed for high-performance data processing on large datasets. Polars utilizes lazy evaluation and query optimization. It leverages multi-threading for faster computations and has a more memory-efficient data representation.
In your specific task Polar significantly outperforms Pandas and Numpy. You can use the following function:
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import string
import time

def filter_sequences_polars(df, threshold=0.5):
    return df.filter(
        pl.col('sequence').str.replace_all('[a-z]', '').str.len_chars() >= 
        (pl.col('sequence').str.len_chars() * threshold)
    )

I have tested this function on 1 million records with each DNA sequence length being 100:
def generate_random_sequence(length):
    return ''.join(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), size=length))

n_records = 1000000
seq_length = 100 

data = {
    'label': np.random.randint(0, 2, n_records),
    'sequence': [generate_random_sequence(seq_length) for _ in range(n_records)]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

start_time = time.time()
filtered_df = filter_sequences_polars(df)
end_time = time.time()

print(f"Time taken: {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")

It took only 5.63 seconds to run which is more than 100 times faster than using Numpy.
Also note that you can easily convert your dataframe from pandas to polars and vice versa:
pandas_df = polars_df.to_pandas()
polars_df = pl.from_pandas(pandas_df )


This is an approach that converts the column into a numpy array of uint8 and then performs the vectorized calculation.
It may consume a large amount of memory, so it depends on the requirements to see if it is effective or not.
import pandas as pd


def remove_low_complexity_seqs(df: pd.DataFrame, threshold=0.5):
    sequence = df["sequence"]

    # This can consume a lot of memory because it creates a matrix of (N, sequence.str.len().max()).
    sequence_as_uint8 = np.array(sequence, dtype="S").view(np.uint8).reshape(len(sequence), -1)

    # Note that ord("A") < ord("a"), and sequence_as_uint8 may contain padding zeros.
    lowercase_count = (sequence_as_uint8 >= ord("a")).sum(axis=1)

    # If you want to compare with sequence length, use sequence.str.len()
    proportion = lowercase_count / 10000
    mask = proportion > threshold
    control_seqs = df[~mask]
    return control_seqs

Using Numba will reduce memory consumption and improve speed slightly. In particular, if the string is long, say over 1000 characters, you should also consider parallelization.
from numba import njit, prange


@njit(cache=True, parallel=True)
def remove_low_complexity_seqs_uint8(sequence, threshold=0.5):
    mask = np.zeros(sequence.shape[0], np.bool_)
    border = ord("a")
    for i in prange(sequence.shape[0]):
        count = 0
        for j in range(sequence.shape[1]):
            if sequence[i, j] >= border:
                count += 1
        if count / 10000 > threshold:
            mask[i] = True
    return mask


def remove_low_complexity_seqs2(df: pd.DataFrame, threshold=0.5):
    sequence = df["sequence"]
    sequence_as_uint8 = np.array(sequence, dtype="S").view(np.uint8).reshape(len(sequence), -1)
    mask = remove_low_complexity_seqs_uint8(sequence_as_uint8, threshold)
    control_seqs = df[~mask]
    return control_seqs


ASCII was made so that upper & lower case letters differ by a single bit
base-char AND ' '  is zero if base-char is uppercase and one if lowercase
note: (space ' '  is 01000000 in binary)
This means your sequences can be efficently reduced to a bit vector indicating case.
Do it in hardware cache sized chunks for speed.
The sideways sum of the bit vector divided by its length gives case proportions.
If a running sum is kept, you can nope out of sequence before finishing.
In an appropriate environment, this has an embarrassingly parallel solution.
In a ram constrained enviroment, trading the sequence for a bitvector
should help if you free the sequence memory once it is reduced to a bitvector.
